# How is FP-Tree used in FP-Growth maintained for large dataset

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, association-rules

I was studying about Association Rule Learning and got to know about FP-Growth algorithm. I am wondering that how is FP-Tree maintained for a really large dataset, for example, that of Amazon and eBay.

- Is the whole dataset stored in just one FP-Tree?
- If not, then how are multiple FP-Tree generated and stored? Like, is the dataset divided or something?